# I am trying to use VBA to copy data from multiple workbooks into a master file without knowing the names of each workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Warning amateur coder...

I am already using this code to open all workbooks in a specific file path

```
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
MyFolder = InputBox("Please enter the folder for files")
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

My next step is trying to copy data from workbooks opened and pasting into the workbook with the code,but not sure how. The problem is that it could be 1-3 possible workbooks opened each time. And it is never the same name

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there only one worksheet or these can vary. Do you want to copy data from one sheet only or from all sheets of a workbook.

Comment: Only one worksheet for each workbook that is opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub OpenFiles()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String, wb As WorkBook

    MyFolder = InputBox("Please enter the folder for files")
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While MyFile <> ""

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)

        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
        wb.Close False

        MyFile = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```